# AWS IoT core certificate quota and pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, client-certificates, aws-iot

all

I am a newbie to AWS IoT core and currently issue devices certificates by fleet provisioning.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/fleet-provision-api.html

I am wondering if there are some limitations or costs of issuing a large number of certificates, e.g. the max number limitation or how much price does N certificates costs.

But I do not find any useful information on AWS's IoT core pricing document.

https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/pricing/?nc1=h_ls

Should I just suppose it has no limitation?

Need some advice.

Comment: See IoT-Core quotas doc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#fleet-provisioning-limits

Comment: @shimo Thanks for your comment, the link offers me additional info I don't know before. But sorry I still find nothing about the maximum limitation and pricing of the number of certificates.

Comment: My guess is that unless you want to provision a billion devices there is no limitation and if there is, amazon will contact you. If you really need to know the limit, contact  their sales team directly. https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/sales-support/

Comment: @Tom thanks a lot! I would contact AWS directly. :D